# Cannot read property of constructed class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am fairly new to TypeScript and I have recently run into a problem I can not solve.

I am creating a REST API with Express. I have a router, which calls a controller and inside the controller, I call a method of a service and then return the response.

This is how my router looks:

```js
import express from 'express';

import { BidsController } from '../../controllers/bids.controller';

const router = express.Router();
const bidsController = new BidsController();

router.post('/bids', isAuthenticated, checkRoles(['user']), checkIsVerified, bidsController.createBid);
```

The router has some middleware, but neither one of them is using bidsController so I do believe they do not cause the error.

This is my bidsController:

```js
import validator from '../validator';
import { BidsService } from '../services/bids.service';

class BidsController implements IBidsController {
  bidsService;

  constructor() {
    this.bidsService = new BidsService();
  }

  async createBid(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    const { params, body } = req;

    try {
      validator.bids.create(params, body);

      const { userId } = res.locals.tokenInfo;
      const { value } = body;

      const response = await this.bidsService.createBid(value, userId);
      res.status(201).json(response);
    } catch (exception) {
      next(exception);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Service:

```js
class BidsService implements IBidsService {
  public async createBid(value: number, userId: string): Promise<IBid> {
    const bid = new Bid({
      value,
      user: userId,
    })

    await bid.save();

    return bid;
  }
}
```

So, when I use Postman to call the POST /bids endpoint, I get the error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'bidsService' of undefined"
```

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: When passed to your router.post() function, bidsController.createBid is not properly bound to the bidsController instance - you're effectively just passing a reference to a function. You need to specify what this inside the function should be at call time. Replace it with bidsController.createBid.bind(bidsController).

Comment: This seems to fix the issue. Is there any way to avoid using bind?

Comment: @GvidasPranauskas yes: `(...args) => bidsController.createBid(...args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
router.post('/bids', isAuthenticated, checkRoles(['user']), 
checkIsVerified, bidsController.createBid.bind(bidsController)); // <- THE FIX
```

First, this is a JS runtime error, not related to TS.

The `this` keyword is dynamically determined when calling “method” of an object.

Usually you directly call the method on that object, like `bidsController.createBid()`. This would bind the `this` keyword inside `createBid` to `bidsController`.

However, in your case, you don’t call it directly. Instead you just pass the value of `bidsController.createBid`, which is a function, to the `router.post` as a callback, which would be called later.

The `this` keyword is unbound in this case, because when it’s called at a later time, it doesn’t have any information about `bidsController`. In order to provide that info, you use `bidsController.createBid.bind(bidsController)` to bind it beforehand.

The other way to bind ahead of time, is to use arrow function when declaring the class method.

```
class BidsController implements IBidsController {

  createBid = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { params, body } = req;
```

Comment: Okay, but is there any way to apply the ```bind``` in other way? It seems too much repetitive code to apply this to every router statement.

Comment: Yes, just saw it. This solve the issue. But why do arrow function does this?

Comment: Arrow function is introduced mainly to solve the this binding problem. That’s what it does.

Comment: Now you’re aware of the devil. I suggest you invest more time to fully understand things about `this` keyword, otherwise, expect future footgun. This is a nasty concept you need to learn the hard way.